# Trying to run java program for first time outside Eclipse

Tags: java

I'm making a simple card game server in Java using eclipse.  I'm now trying to get it to run outside of eclipse.
I did the following

1. exported it as a jar file, called car4dgameserver.jar
2. tried to run it by typing  `java car4dgameserver`

I keep getting a error that says

```
Error:could not find or load main class car4dgameserver
```

any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is execute it like so:

```
java -jar card4dgameserver.jar
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `-jar` option and provide the path to the jar file:

```
java -jar car4dgameserver.jar
```